# styling placeholder pseudo only works on focus?

Tags: css, placeholder

I'm having 'issues' styling CSS with HTML5 placeholder in FF and Chrome. Example:

```
http://jchmusic.com
```

...click the 'Contact' main menu.

It seems that if the form is position: absolute, the placeholder text pseudo style -only- works if the field is in focus (selected). Otherwise, it just reverts to the styling of the 'real' element.

If the form is position: relative, works fine.

Here is the code I'm using

```
input:-moz-placeholder{color:#999; font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace}
input:-ms-input-placeholder{color:#999; font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
 color:    #999; font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
 color:    #999; font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
color:    #999 !important;
     font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
color:    #999;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace
}
```

I read a couple of anecdotes here regarding 'hover', but I don't know if that applies to my situation. Is there a workaround with CSS or do I just need to fall back to jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code and i'm noticing that some javascript is adding

```
class="placeholder"
```

to the inputs when are not selected, that may be changing the behavior of normal placeholder.
This looks like some jQueryUI intervention

Comment: You da man. Confused because that code is -not- interfering with another form and the only obvious difference I could see was the absolute positioning. Haven't figured out -why- it interferes, but yeah, that jQuery definitely -is- the issue. Thx.

Comment: It think it is a workaround jQueryUI does for "fixing" some placeholder issues. Maybe you can just overide the _placeholder_ class